# Issue while Paginating in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination

I am trying to implement a pagination to my table that I am displaying but I am getting `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

Here is my component.ts

```
     getdata: any[];
    curPage: number;
    pageSize: number;

    ngOnInit() {

        this.getData();

    }


    getData() {
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        let getUrl = 'http://jsonstub.com/v1/configs';
        return this.http.get(getUrl, {headers: headers})
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.getdata  = res.json();
            console.log(this.getdata.length);
        });
    }

    numberOfPages() {
    return Math.ceil(this.getdata.length / this.pageSize);
  };
```

And my HTML is below :

```
            <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let mem of getdata | FilterPipe: queryString | slice: (curPage * pageSize) - pagSize :curPage * pageSize">
                <td>
                    <a (click)="getFormgroup(mem.configName) ? addtionalInfo = true : addtionalInfo = false" class="clickable">{{mem.configName}}</a>
                </td>
                <td>{{mem.sources.length}}</td>
                <td>
                    <span *ngFor="let sourceNames of mem.sources; let last=last">
                        {{sourceNames.sourceId}}<span *ngIf="!last">, </span> 
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <p class="pagination">
                <button [disabled] = "curPage == 1" (click)="curPage = curPage - 1">PREV</button>
                <span> Page {{curPage}} of {{ numberOfPages() }}</span>
                <button [disabled] = "curPage >= getdata.length/pageSize" (click) = "curPage = curPage + 1">NEXT</button>
            </p>
        </tbody>
```

my `getdata` is an array like below with length of 4.

```
[
{configName: "A", sources: Array(1), queryTimeThresholdInMs: 0},
{configName: "B", sources: Array(3), queryTimeThresholdInMs: 5},
{configName: "C", sources: Array(2), queryTimeThresholdInMs: 5},
{configName: "D", sources: Array(2), queryTimeThresholdInMs: 0}
]
```

I think my logic is correct and also, I am doing `getdata.length` on an array, hence not sure why this error is popping up.

**EDIT**: I updated by `getdata()` function to call `numberofPages()` after `http.get` but I get the same error.

```
    getData() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let getUrl = 'http://jsonstub.com/v1/configs';
    return this.http.get(getUrl, {headers: headers})
    .subscribe(res => {
        this.getdata  = res.json();
        console.log(this.getdata);
    },
    () => {
        this.numberOfPages();
    });

}
```

Comment: @Vega It is an array of formgroups.

Comment: @Vega Well, I am just getting the data in json format in `getdata` and displaying the sources part as `{{mem.sources.length}}`

Comment: In which line do you get the error? Inside the `subscribe` callback, or in the line `return Math.ceil(this.getdata.length / this.pageSize)`? Because of course you're going to get an error in the latter case.

Comment: @kshetline Yes, I get an error on that return statement and in HTML it points to `<button [disabled] = "curPage == 1" (click)="curPage = curPage - 1">PREV</button>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of asynchronous timing. You get the error in `return Math.ceil(this.getdata.length / this.pageSize)` because there's nothing in your code to ensure that the `subscribe` callback from your `http.get` has completed execution first.

Make sure you don't call your `numberOfPages()` method until the `http.get` has completed successful execution.

You can get rid of the error by initializing `getdata` like this:

```
getdata: any[] = [];
```

A least this way `numberOfPages()` will at first return 0 rather than failing with an error. With the error circumvented, this might even properly update from 0 to the correct number of pages once the `http.get` response is received.

Comment: I am ensuring that my calling the `http.get` on `ngOnInit()`

Comment: Yes, but calling `http.get` after `ngOnInit()` isn’t enough here. It doesn’t ensure the timing of `numberOfPages` after the http response. I’d explain more, but I’m on my phone now and technical stuff is hard to type!

Comment: Please check my question. I have edited my function.

Comment: I've looked over your code as it is now, and there's still nothing to fix the timing problem. I'll suggest a workaround by editing my answer above.